# Would this be a good way to do private functions?

Tags: javascript

Just saw some interesting code while doing a typo in coffee-script. I got the following code

```
var Mamal, mam;

Mamal = (function() {
  var __priv_func;

  function Mamal() {}

  Mamal.prototype.simple_var = 5;

  Mamal.prototype.test = function() {
    return __priv_func(this);
  };

  __priv_func = function(instance) {
    return alert(instance.simple_var);
  };

  return Mamal;

})();

mam = new Mamal();
mam.simple_var = 10;
mam.test();
```

Now I've read alot about the module pattern in javascript and why its a bad thing (takes more memory, longer to create...) but of course the upside is having truly private functions/variables. Wouldn't the above code be a good way to create private functions (this wouldn't work for variables, unless you wanted static private variables) as the function is only created once in the closure?

One of the upsides of the module pattern is also the execution speed of functions as the code doesn't have to look up the prototype chain. Would this theoretically give the same speed improvements?

Comment: The only thing I'd change is not pass in an instance into the private method, but use `.call(this)` instead.

Comment: *"One of the upsides of functional inheritance is also the execution speed of functions as the code doesn't have to look up the prototype chain. Would this theoretically give the same speed improvements?"* No, because you're still using prototypal inheritance, not functional inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To highlight the points I was making, because clearly there was more to the question than just the title:***

- Yes a module pattern is a good and commonly used way to create private (er, local) data (functions or whatever), and export some sort of interface. Since a function is the *only* way to create variable scope, it's the *only* way to create private functions.
- Because the functions will be shared by all objects created from `Mamal`, they're not useful for a *functional inheritance* pattern *(references to functional inheritance have been removed from the question)*.
- There's no performance improvement over lookups in the prototype chain, because the prototype chain needs to be traversed anyway just to get to your private functions.

---

***To address specific questions points in the updated post:***

> *"Would this be a good way to do private functions?"*

Sure, but that's because having a function nested in another is the *only* way to scope a function.

> *"Now I've read alot about the module pattern in javascript and why its a bad thing..."*

For a one-time use module, I don't see any issue. Also, any data referenced by variables that are no longer needed after the module function exits is free for garbage collection. This wouldn't be the case if they were global, unless you nullified them.

> *"...of course the upside is having truly private functions/variables...*"

Yes, though some would take exception to the use of the word "private". Probably "local" is a better word.

> *"...this wouldn't work for variables, unless you wanted static private variables..."*

Yes, though again some may take exception to the use of the word "static".

> *"Wouldn't the above code be a good way to create private functions...as the function is only created once in the closure?"*

Yes again, nested functions are the only way to make them "private" or rather local.

But yes, as long as the function only ever needs to access the public properties of the objects *(which are accessible to any code that can access the object)* and not local variables of the constructor, then you should only create those functions once, whether or not you use a module pattern.

> *"One of the upsides of the module pattern is also the execution speed of functions as the code doesn't have to look up the prototype chain. Would this theoretically give the same speed improvements?"*

No, you haven't exported your private functions directly, but rather the only way to call them is by traversing the prototype chain.

But if you ditched the prototype chain, and added functions as properties directly on the objects created, then you'd have some improvement there.

Here's an example:

```
Mamal = (function() {
  var __priv_func;

  function Mamal() {
    this.test = __priv_func;
  }

  Mamal.prototype.simple_var = 5;

  __priv_func = function() {
    return alert( this.simple_var );
  };

  return Mamal;

})();
```

Now you've eliminated the prototype chain in the lookup of the `test` function, and also the wrapped function call, and you're still reusing the `__priv_func`.

The only thing left that is prototyped is the `simple_var`, and you could bring that directly onto the object too, but that'll happen anyway when you try to modify its value, so you might as well leave it there.

---

***Original answer:***

If you're talking about a *module pattern*, where you set up a bunch of code in (typically) an IIFE, then export methods that have access to the variables in the anonymous function, then yes, it's a good approach, and is pretty common.

```
var MyNamespace = (function () {
    // do a bunch of stuff to set up functionality
    //    without pollution global namespace

    var _exports = {};

    _exports.aFunction = function() { ... };
    _exports.anotherFunction = function() { ... };

    return _exports;
})();

MyNamespace.aFunction();
```

But in your example, I don't see and advantage over a typical constructor, unless you decide to use the module pattern as above.

The way it stands right now, the identical functionality can be accomplished like this without any more global pollution, and without the wrapped function:

```
var Mamal, mam;

Mamal = function() {};

Mamal.prototype.test = function() {
    return console.log(this.simple_var);
};

Mamal.prototype.simple_var = 5;

mam = new Mamal();
mam.simple_var = 10;
mam.test();
```

---

> *" Wouldn't the above code be a good way to create private functions (this wouldn't work for variables, unless you wanted static private variables) as the function is only created once in the closure?"*

Given the rewritten code above, the function is still only created once. The prototype object is shared between objects created from the constructor, so it too is only created once.

> *"One of the upsides of functional inheritance is also the execution speed of functions as the code doesn't have to look up the prototype chain. Would this theoretically give the same speed improvements?"*

In your code, the function is called via a function in the prototype chain, so it has that same overhead, plus the overhead of finding the local function in the variable scope and invoking that function as well.

So two lookups and two function invocation instead of one lookup and one invocation.

Comment: I think his main goal is to have private functions, not polluting global. In your second rewrite everything is public.

Comment: @MattGreer: Yes, I could see that you'd want to have some private functions or data, and only expose a limited interface. But that would be a typical module pattern. The second example doesn't really pollute the global namespace any more than his original code, but with additional functions it could. But if the intention is to just have prototyped functions that simply wrap a call to a local function, then there really is no advantage, and just overhead.

Comment: it doesnt pollute the global namespace because you in-lined `__priv_func` inside the publicly accessible function `test`, which was the entire point of the question... The question is: if you wanted to have private methods, but didn't want to incur the cost of generating distinct private members inside the constructor, is this (scoping private members inside a self-executing closure) a viable, more performant alternative? I fear you missed the point of the question entirely.

Comment: @32bitkid: But if you read the first half of my answer, you'll see that I addressed that. The question though seems to have several points. Especially considering the last quote about speed improvements, I'm not entirely sure that OP isn't just using simple functn wrappers for a perceived benefit. Also with the quote about the function being created once, some people think that the `prototype` object is duplicated for each object constructed, instead of being shared. So until there's an example given that takes specific advantage of the module, I see more that points to some misunderstandings.

Comment: @RightSaidFred hes talking about the functional inheritance pattern, not a misunderstanding about how prototypes work. see http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php

Comment: I was never talking about the prototype object, I'm well aware that it's only created once. What I am talking about is the __priv_function. Since it's a part of the imidiate functions closure, __priv_function will only be created once AND it will be private (impossible to alter outside that imidiate function). The drawback of using the module pattern (functional inheritance) is that functions are created for every "instance", my code should however, only creates the private function once...

Comment: @32bitkid: But in the example, functional inheritance isn't used. It's just a typical constructor that utilizes prototypal inheritance. Yes the prototyped methods have access to the private functions, but that's just as a convenience of not polluting the global. There's no aspect of inheritance there that I can see.

Comment: @RobinHeggelundHansen: But you're *using* the prototype object for inheritance. The only inheritance that's happening comes from your `Mamal` constructor's prototype object. Yes, the prototyped functions reference some other functions that were created in a closure, but I don't see any benefit beyond preventing namespace pollution and limiting access to those functions.

Comment: ...unless you have something specific in mind, I'd say that the way the code is currently written, there's no benefit, and just overhead. Unless `Mamal.prototype.test` is meant to do more than it currently does, your `__priv_func` is effectively exposed. `var func = mam.test; func.apply( {simple_var:'hijacked'} );` You have a one time use IIFE, so the only opportunity to create instances that benefit from any type of inheritance is via the prototypal inheritance afforded by the constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry on the wrong use of terminology, i mean the module pattern, not functional inheritance. The question however does not concern inheritance at all, but if this is a good way to create private functions. In the module pattern, private functions are recreated for every "instance" of the module/class, in my code however, the private function should only be created once inside the closure of the class definition... So shouldn't this bring the convinience of private function, without the penalty of the module pattern (long create times).

Comment: @RobinHeggelundHansen: Yes that makes more sense now. But typically the module pattern (as I've seen it anyway) is a one-time use structure, and isn't used to create multiple "instances", though there could be more than one *different* module in an application. There are elements of your question that do concern inheritance, like your reference to the performance of the prototype chain. That's an inheritance pattern question. But yes, as I state at the top, it's a good and common practice, but isn't so much unique to your usage of returning a constructor. jQuery, for example, does that.

Comment: @32bitkid: Looking back at your comments, *"but didn't want to incur the cost of generating distinct private members..."* but then *"hes talking about the functional inheritance pattern..."*, the trouble is that one approach is not a replacement for the other. Functional inheritance *requires* the cost of distinct private methods, so things just weren't adding up. Robin's clarifying comment was helpful.

Comment: @RobinHeggelundHansen: I updated my answer to go over a bit of the confusion, but mostly to address your points in the updated question, and to show an alternative that would offer the performance benefit over the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Mamal, mam1, mam2;

Mamal = (function() {
  //private static method
  var __priv_func = function() {
    return 1;
  };

  function Mamal() {
  }

  Mamal.prototype.get = function() {
        return __priv_func();
  };

  Mamal.prototype.set = function(i) {
        __priv_func = function(){
          return i;
        };
  };

  return Mamal;

})();

mam1 = new Mamal();
mam2 = new Mamal();
console.log(mam1.get()); //output 1
mam2.set(2);
console.log(mam1.get()); //output 2
```

The function __priv_func is not only private, but also static. I think it's a good way to get private function if 'static' does not matter.

Below is a way to get private but not static method. It may take more memory, longer to create.......

```
var Mamal, mam1, mam2;

function Mamal() {
  //private attributes
  var __priv_func = function() {
    return 1;
  };

  //privileged methods
  this.get = function() {
      return __priv_func();
  };
  this.set = function(i) {
      __priv_func = function(){
        return i;
      };
  };
}

mam1 = new Mamal();
mam2 = new Mamal();
console.log(mam1.get()); // output 1
console.log(mam2.get()); // output 1
mam2.set(2);
console.log(mam1.get()); // output 1
console.log(mam2.get()); // output 2
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer my question regarding if the way i did private and static function, is better than creating private functions using the module pattern.

Comment: What kind of module pattern do you use?  Can you show the code? As far as I know, some module pattern get private function as the way of your code.